# TypeError: fs.readdirSync is not a function when using Winston logger in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging, fs, winston

I am developing an application in React (using JavaScript) and I want to create a log file using the package Winston-react.
I have followed their tutorial from here: https://github.com/afex-connect/winston-react#readme (obviously adapted to javascript)

Install

```
npm install winston-react
```

Usage
App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import winston from 'winston';
import { WinstonProvider } from 'winston-react';

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  // ...
  transports: [
    // ...
    new winston.transports.Console()
  ]
});

const App = () => (
  <WinstonProvider logger={logger}>
    <div>
      your awesome application
    </div>
  </WinstonProvider>
);
```

Using hooks:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useWinstonLogger } from 'winston-logger';

const Component = () => {
  const logger = useWinstonLogger();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    logger.info('your awesome information log!');
  });

  return (
    <div>
      your awesome component
    </div>
  );
};
```

But it is throwing this error:
`TypeError: fs.readdirSync is not a function`

```
node_modules/pkginfo/lib/pkginfo.js:95
  92 |   dir = path.dirname(pmodule.filename);
  93 | }
  94 | 
> 95 | var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
     | ^  96 | 
  97 | if (~files.indexOf('package.json')) {
  98 |   return path.join(dir, 'package.json');
```

Comment: can you create an example on codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your application in node or in a browser? The `fs` module does not exist in the browser.

Also, if you want to create a log file then you need to use the `File` transport. Your code sample only shows the `Console` transport, which will write to the console.

Comment: How to do that? Because as per their tutorial, using fs should work